# Android how to wait for onComplete method to end before proceeding to the next code

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to get a boolean from my onComplete function before proceeding to the next step.

My problem is that when code gets to the part when my boolean (isLoginSucces) is crucial to my code, it get's only false value, because onComplete function did not arrived at the point when it changes the value of the boolean.

I tried async function, but it didn't work, tried aswell AtomicBoolean, didn't worked too.

After that, i did put even Thread.sleep(10000). In that time(10 seconds) it surely changed the value, but don't work too, still false, i don't get it.

```
    private String loginButtonClicked () {

            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        ...
                        LoginFragment.this.isLoginSucces = true;
                        Log.d("boolean", "boolean value in onComplete: " + isLoginSucces);
                    } else {
                        ...
                        LoginFragment.this.isLoginSucces = false;
                    }
                }
            });

            //HERE I tried Thread.sleep(10000);
            Log.d("boolean", "boolean value after function: " + isLoginSucces);

            if (LoginFragment.this.isLoginSucces)
                return email;
            else
                return null;

    }
```

> The log output is :
>
> 2019-03-29 18:45:12 D/boolean: boolean value after function: false
>
> 2019-03-29 18:45:14 D/boolean: boolean value in onComplete: true

Comment: In general you don't.  That's a callback function.  It means work is going to be either done on another thread, or on this thread but at a later time.  There are some situations where you can do so safely, but not in general.  Instead your code should be written to not wait for the result.  This is ESPECIALLY true if this is the main thead-  in that case it should NEVER wait for anything.  Doing so would at base cause unresponsiveness, at worst cause a hang

Comment: But i need onComplete function, only in this way it works to get data from Firebase. I don't know other way.

Comment: RIght-  so your code that uses the result of onComplete should go in onComplete.  You shouldn't wait for it to be called.  Instead, you should not use the results of the call until it is, and display a loading UI if needed until then

Comment: Yes, i get what do you say, but I need it to return a value, and as you know, onComplete is the type _void_ . Can't return anything from it, aswell, can't retrieve the information needed from a variable, because it will get over it fast.

Comment: You need to refactor your code to call a function in onComplete that has all the code that runs after you are calling this method.  This method will be void and anything that requires that String is in the method that you call in onComplete.  That's the only way to ensure the results are ready for you to use.

Comment: @Parthanon Yes, except the Android OS specifically DOES NOT ALLOW THIS.  In lifecycle methods, it will trip the watchdog.  In non-lifecycle methods its possible (as long as you don't delay a lifecycle method that needs to run), but doing so will freeze all UI and event handling.  In other words, you don't do it.  Ever.  YOu should understand the platform before commenting on things

Comment: @GabeSechan It's all great telling me that it only applies to Android, but you didn't mention this little "BTW" in your original comment. This is not in fact basic asynchronous programming, where this would be possible. This is basic Android UI thread programming. A topic I might add that is difficult to find conclusive documentation about due to androids documentation being all over the place. Please try to understand the asker's situation before saying "It's basic programming 101 dude get good.". Stack Overflow is not known for being a great community and you're not helping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233356/discussion-between-parthanon-and-gabe-sechan).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void methodThatCallsLoginButtonClicked() {
    // code before calling loginButtonClicked 

    loginButtonClicked();

    // nothing else that needs the value from login button clicked should be here
}

public void afterLogin(boolean result) {
    // any code that needs the value of the login callback
}

private void loginButtonClicked () {

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                afterLogin(task.isSuccessful());
            }
        });

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare

```
String str_email = "";
```

at the top of your code.

Insert dependent code inside oncomplete method removing the return statement and changing for:

```
private String loginButtonClicked () {

            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    ...
                    LoginFragment.this.isLoginSucces = true;
                    Log.d("boolean", "boolean value in onComplete: " + isLoginSucces);
                } else {
                    ...
                    LoginFragment.this.isLoginSucces = false;
                }

               if (LoginFragment.this.isLoginSucces)
                   str_email = email;
               else
                   str_email = ";

        });
}
```

Do your code with

```
if(!str_email.equals("")){

//if str_email is different from ""


}
```

Comment: Still same result, see log:2019-03-29 19:08:16.423 D/boolean: str value after function: 
2019-03-29 19:08:17.570 D/boolean: str value in onComplete: ainkiwi@gmail.com

Comment: Still get's outside the onComplete function with the null value